# Using aliases in subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I'm using Alias to indicate the number of students in universities, but it gives an error "incorrect variable name".

```
select  MAX (numb_stud)
from
    ( select count(*) numb_stud
      from Student
      Group by ID_University )
```

I use MS SQL SERVER. When Oracle is used, there were no such problems.

Comment: You need to alias your subquery.  `SELECT MAX(numb_stud) FROM (...) AS t;`.

Comment: From (subquery) as something

Comment: Your error was not `incorrect variable name` it was `Incorrect syntax near ')'.` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1364d215fb6fb37f8fb62295efa13db7 please always give the exact error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are missing the ALIAS of your sub query. You need to do it like below :

```
select  MAX (numb_stud)
from
    ( select count(*) numb_stud
      from Student
      Group by ID_University ) AS Table1
```